# Sqlite c++ ATTACH memory database

Tags: c++, sqlite, in-memory-database

I try to attach in memory db to an existing db connection via c++ api like this:

```
void InMemoryDbtest(){
    sqlite3 *db;
    int rc = sqlite3_open("E:/VS_workspace/ConsoleSQLITE/Debug/TPCH.sqlite", &db);
    if (rc){
        cout << "nie moge otworzyc bazy danych ";}
    else{
        cout << "otwarcie bazy ---- udalo sie\n";}
    char *err;

sqlite3_exec(db, "ATTACH DATABASE 'file::memory:?cache=shared' as pom",0,0,&err);

    cout << "error" << err << endl;
    string q = "create table pom.bla as select n_name from NATION ";
    sqlite3_exec(db, q.c_str(), 0, 0, &err);
    cout << "error" << err << endl;
}
```

I get 2 error messages"

unable to open database: file:memory
and
unknown database pom

Any ideas? When i try to attach db in sqlite console everything works just fine

Comment: Could you try this in sqlite3_open(): file:///E:/VS_workspace/ConsoleSQLITE/Debug/TPCH.sqlite

Comment: Now its worse as TPCH.sqlite wont open. Previously TPCH.sqlite opened but i couldnt attach inmemory db to it.

Comment: See documentation under "URI Filename Examples" and "Notes to Windows users" here: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html - Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions the solution is:

first : set SQLITE_USE_URI flag in sqlite3.c to 1 instead of 0 (just using SQLITE_OPEN_URI flag with sqlite3_open_v2() wsn't enough)

```
#ifndef SQLITE_USE_URI
# define  SQLITE_USE_URI 1
#endif
```

then you can use uri's with all sqlite3 functions.

proper uri for windows is:

```
int rc2 = sqlite3_open("file:///E:/VS_workspace/ConsoleSQLITE/Debug/TPCH.sqlite", &db);
```